# My CNN image recognition model produces fluctuating validation loss

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

My model is experiencing wild and big fluctuations in the validation loss and does not converge.

I am doing an image recognition project with my three dogs i.e. classifying the dog in the image. Two dogs are very similar and the 3rd is very different. I took 10 minute videos of each dog, separately. Frames were extracted as images at each second. My dataset consists of about 1800 photos, 600 of each dog.

This block of code is responsible for augmenting and creating the data to feed the model.

```
randomize = np.arange(len(imArr)) # imArr is the numpy array of all the images
np.random.shuffle(randomize) # Shuffle the images and labels
imArr = imArr[randomize]
imLab= imLab[randomize] # imLab is the array of labels of the images
lab = to_categorical(imLab, 3)

gen = ImageDataGenerator(zoom_range = 0.2,horizontal_flip = True , vertical_flip = True,validation_split = 0.25)
train_gen = gen.flow(imArr,lab,batch_size = 64, subset = 'training')
test_gen = gen.flow(imArr,lab,batch_size =64,subset = 'validation')
```

This picture is the result of the model below.[image]

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, (11, 11),strides = 1, input_shape=(imgSize,imgSize,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))


model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5),strides = 1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides = 2))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))




#Fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(3))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.004)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 64
epochs = 100
model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=(len(train_gen)), epochs=epochs, validation_data=test_gen, validation_steps=len(test_gen),shuffle = True)
```

Things I have tried.

- High/low Learning rate  ( 0.01 -> 0.0001)
- Increase Dropout to 0.5 in both Dense layers
- Increase/Decrease size of both Dense Layers ( 128 min -> 4048 max)
- Increased number of CNN layers
- Introduced Momentum
- Increased/Decreased Batch Size

Things I have not tried

- I have not used any other loss or metric
- I have not used any other optimiser.
- Have not adjusted any parameters of the CNN layers

It seems that there is some form of randomness or too many parameters in my model. I am aware that it is currently overfitting, but that should not be the cause of the volatility(?).
I am not too worried about the performance of the model. I would like to achieve about a 70% accuracy. All I want to do now is to stabilise the validation accuracy and to converge.

Note:

- At some epochs, the training loss is very low ( <0.1 ) but validation
  loss is     very high ( > 3 ).
- The videos are taken on different backgrounds, but +- the same amount on each background for each dog.
- Some images are a bit blurry.

Comment: Hi @RabboPasch, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Change the optimizer to Adam, definitely better. In your code you are using it but with default parameters, you are creating an SGD optimizer but in the compile line you introduce an Adam with no parameters. Play with the actual parameters of your optimizer.

I encourage you to take out the dropout first, see what is happening and the if you manage to overfit, start with low dropout and go up.

Also it might be due to some of your test samples are very hard to detect and thus increase the loss, maybe take out the shuffle in the validation set and watch for any peridiocities to try to find out if there are validation samples hard to detect.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I manually scanned through all the images and removed useless photos and that did seem to help the fluctuations a bit.

Regarding the optimizer, Ill try different parameters using Adam and report back.

The model was definitely overfitting when I did not include any dropouts, and 0.3 seemed to hit the spot.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds nice. The quality of the data should not be underestimated. I will wait for your feature advances!

Comment: Yep, that can be said again. I played around with different optimizers and as of now, Adagrad is minimising the fluctuations.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have tried a lot of different things. Few suggestions:

1. I see you use large filters in your `Conv2D` eg. `11x11` and `5x5`. If your image dimensions are not very big, you should definitely go for lower filter dimensions like `3x3`.
2. Try different optimizers, try `Adam` with varying `lr` if you haven't.

Otherwise, I don't see much problems. Maybe you need more data for the network to learn better.

Comment: I will definitely try different parameters with Adam, thanks.

My Images are quite big, 256 x 256. The model improved when I included a conv layer with larger filters, as big as 21.

Comment: I played around with a few optimizers. Adagrad seemed to be working the best with respect to the fluctuations.

Comment: Makes kind of sense as Adagrad doesn't havr adaptive momentum, so the momentum is actually going against you, causing more fluctuations. Rmsprop or Adadelta might be even better in that case. Adagrad does have the problem of decaying updates if you are planning for large number of epochs.